# Dimension length of ncdf file differs

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm New to R and I am trying to plot grid with R for some few days, but unsuccessful.
I got precipitation data from ecmwf ERA Interim for 2013 in my region and i cant plot grid because dimension length of my ncdf file differs. It would be really great if someone could help me.

My .nc data in Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0X5ssvd281gUnIyUkZHRGs1a0k/edit?usp=sharing

i use code:

```
> library(ncdf)
> precipitation = open.ncdf("precipitation_2013.nc")
> lonmat  = get.var.ncdf(nc= precipitation,varid="longitude")
> latmat  = get.var.ncdf(nc= precipitation,varid="latitude")
> plot(lonmat, latmat, main= "Precipitation grid 2013")
```

Thanks for any help:)

Comment: No cross posting!  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97371/dimension-length-of-netcdf-file-differs

Comment: I'll answer this question here since this is in my opinion a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never dealt with geo-NetCDF files, but when you look at the file you see what actually is going on:

```
print(precipitation)
[1] "file ~/Downloads/precipitation_2013.nc has 3 dimensions:"
[1] "longitude   Size: 8"
[1] "latitude   Size: 5"
[1] "time   Size: 730"
[1] "------------------------"
[1] "file ~/Downloads/precipitation_2013.nc has 1 variables:"
[1] "short tp[longitude,latitude,time]  Longname:Total precipitation Missval:-32767"
```

Your actual data has one variable of type `short` with three dimensions `longitude`, `latitude` and `time`. The values of the dimensions are stored as as separate variables while the variable collecting the values just references the dimensions. So the question is independent of a *NetCDF* or *geographic information system* question: What is it, that you actually want to plot when having the values

```
> latmat
[1] 60.0 58.5 57.0 55.5 54.0
> lonmat
[1] 19.5 21.0 22.5 24.0 25.5 27.0 28.5 30.0
```

You can comprise your data by extracting the actual variable, bring it in long format and assign the dimension values to the resulting `data.frame`:

```
library(reshape2)
tp.molten <- melt(get.var.ncdf(nc= precipitation,varid="tp"), varnames=c("longitude", "latitude", "time"))
tp.molten$longitude <- lonmat[tp.molten$longitude]
tp.molten$latitude <- lonmat[tp.molten$latitude ]
tp.molten$time<- get.var.ncdf(nc= precipitation,varid="time")[tp.molten$time ]

close.ncdf( precipitation ) # don't forget

head(tp.molten)
longitude latitude   time       value
1      19.5     19.5 990564 0.002813700
2      21.0     19.5 990564 0.004143370
3      22.5     19.5 990564 0.006473583
4      24.0     19.5 990564 0.008655690
5      25.5     19.5 990564 0.007778240
6      27.0     19.5 990564 0.005223891
```

Now you could for instance subset these data by one timepoint and plot this on a lon-lat-grid

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot( data = tp.molten[ tp.molten$time == 992052, ], aes( x = latitude, y = longitude, fill = value ) ) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]